# WHM - Restart Apache

Tags: apache, restart, whm

I need to restart apache in order to recover from a server crash. I am looking for "restart services" in WHM VPS Optimized and I can't seem to find it nowhere. Can you help? Thank you.

Comment: What does `WHM` stand for?

Answer (score 4):

Here you could do quick fix

1. Login to WHM
2. On the left side there search option type there "Restart"
3. HTTP Server (Apache)
4. Once you click on the right side there is blue button to Restart service

If it shows you success msg then HTTP server restart success & if any error then contact server administrator/hosting comapany from where you pruchased hosting or connect via SSH and try sending command

httpd restart

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Are you by chance hosting on hostgator VPS? If so, the answer was "oh, you have to use VZ". I didn't know what that was, apparently it is the Parallels Virtual Automation software that is a very low-level server admin tool that sits on port 4643 (for Hostgator at least). From there I was able to see the httpd service listed and restarted it from there.

There's an easier answer though - log in to your VPS through ssh as root and simply execute "service httpd restart". This should also do the trick.